# MacOSX Server accessed from Screen Sharing not allowing to change Access Control

Tags: macos, permissions, certificate, screen-sharing, access-control

I have a Mac Mini working as a **build server** for my iOS apps.

However, the XCode Server daemon runs with special permissions, that requires certificates to be added in the **System keychain**. 
In order for it to work, I need to grant access to the certificate private key to all users, otherwise XCode will prompt for permission, which of course breaks the build as this computer is unattended.

When I try to change the **KeyChain Access Control** permission from remote (using Screen Sharing), the system prompts me for an admin password, but **it does not accept i**t

Screenshot of System password dialog

[image]

There is no feedback, the screen just does not react.

However, when I do it with a **physically attached keyboard**, then the setting is saved normally.

Is this a normal behaviour? **can it be disabled somehow**? Any workaround? The build server will be stored in a different location and it is quite common to have to install new certificates, so physical access is not a workable solution for me.

Comment: Are you logged into the computer as **root** ?

Comment: No. root is not listed as a user on the account selection, so I log in as myself (a user with Admin privileges), and then I try root (and my own) in this password prompt. And same thing works without Remote Screen Sharing.

Comment: You must enter your username and password not root

Comment: I tried that already :). There is a first prompt where my username is allowed, but then this second prompt comes in and none of them work (mine or root). As explained, it works if I plug a keyboard instead of Screen Sharing, so I think it is related to the remote management somehow.